# How to close second window without closing entire sketch in Processing?

Tags: java, jframe, window, processing

I'm working on a prototype for software for my work. I've managed through examples and tutorials to create a second window for additional options which is great. Except for the fact that closing that window closes the entire sketch. I want to make it so hitting either the window control close button or closing the window via code will only close that second window and not the entire sketch.

I've looked everywhere for tutorials and code examples, but am struggling to implement anything at all usable. Any advice or tips or pointers here would be much appreciated!

Here is the full code of the project so far (so you can get a look at how I implemented the second window)

Thank you!

```
import controlP5.*;

ControlP5 cp5;

PFont f_bebasNeueBold;

int resW = 1600;
int resH = 900;

int numOfLayouts = 0;

StringList layoutsFileData;
StringList testingArr;

String currentSpreadTitle = "null";
String parentPath;

ChildApplet newLayoutWindow;

//basic ui initialization
ui_window programHeader = new ui_window(0,0,resW,75,(#1D4077));
ui_window toolBar = new ui_window(0,75,resW,35,(#12284B));
ui_window infoPanel = new ui_window(15,programHeader.windowHeight + toolBar.windowHeight + 15,400,resH - 30 - programHeader.windowHeight - toolBar.windowHeight,(#12284B)); 
ui_window infoPanelHeader = new ui_window(15,infoPanel.windowYPos,400,60,(#1D4077));
//basic ui initialization

void setup() {
  size(1600,900);
  surface.setTitle("WarBoard - V.0.1");
  background(#F2F4F3);
  
  parentPath = sketchPath();
  
  //controlP5 elements
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  
  ControlFont cf_buttonFont = new ControlFont(createFont("Bebas Neue Pro Bold.otf",14));
  
  cp5.addButton("buttonNewLayout")
     .setValue(0)
     .setPosition(10,toolBar.windowYPos + (toolBar.windowHeight / 2) - 10)
     .setSize(100,20)
     .setCaptionLabel("New Layout")
     .setColorBackground(color(#F2F4F3))
     .setColorForeground(color(#BFBFBF))
     .setColorActive(color(#999999))
     .setColorCaptionLabel(color(#12284B))
     .setFont(cf_buttonFont)
     .setBroadcast(false)
     .addCallback(new CallbackListener() {
       public void controlEvent(CallbackEvent event) {
         if (event.getAction() == ControlP5.ACTION_RELEASED) {
           launchNewLayoutWindow();
         }
       }
     }
     );
     ;
  //controlP5 elements
  
  layoutsFileData = new StringList();
  testingArr = new StringList();
  
  f_bebasNeueBold = createFont("Bebas Neue Pro Bold.otf", 1000);
  
  if (checkFileStructure()) {
    String tempFileData[] = loadStrings("data/layouts.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < tempFileData.length; i++) {
      layoutsFileData.append(tempFileData[i]);
    }
  }
  else {
    String setupFileStruct = "0|";
    String[] fileStruct = split(setupFileStruct, '|');
    saveStrings("data/layouts.txt", fileStruct);
    
    String tempFileData[] = loadStrings("data/layouts.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < tempFileData.length; i++) {
      layoutsFileData.append(tempFileData[i]);
    }  
    numOfLayouts = 0;
  }
  
  numOfLayouts = int(layoutsFileData.get(0));
  
  testingArr.append("1");
  testingArr.append("2");
  newLayout("Test Layout", testingArr);
  
}

void draw() {
  programHeader.update();
  toolBar.update();
  infoPanel.update();
  infoPanelHeader.update();
  
  easyText("WARBOARD", width/2, (programHeader.windowHeight / 2) - 15, 32, (#F2F4F3), CENTER, CENTER);
  easyText("VERSION 0.1", width/2, (programHeader.windowHeight / 2) + 15, 24, (#F2F4F3), CENTER, CENTER);
  
  easyText(currentSpreadTitle, infoPanelHeader.windowXPos + (infoPanelHeader.windowWidth / 2), infoPanelHeader.windowYPos + (infoPanelHeader.windowHeight / 2), 32, (#F2F4F3), CENTER, CENTER);
}

class ui_window {
  color fillColor;
  float windowWidth, windowHeight;
  float windowXPos, windowYPos;
  
  ui_window (float x, float y, float inputWidth, float inputHeight, color inputColor) {
    windowXPos = x;
    windowYPos = y;
    windowWidth = inputWidth;
    windowHeight = inputHeight;
    fillColor = inputColor;
  }
  
  void update() {
    noStroke();
    fill(fillColor);
    rect(windowXPos, windowYPos, windowWidth, windowHeight);
  }
  
}

void easyText(String textDisplay, float textXPos, float textYPos, float textFontSize, color textColor, int textFontAlignX, int textFontAlignY) {
  noStroke();
  fill(textColor);
  textFont(f_bebasNeueBold);
  textSize(textFontSize);
  textAlign(textFontAlignX, textFontAlignY);
  text(textDisplay, textXPos, textYPos);
}

void newLayout(String layoutName, StringList layoutPositions) {
  
  layoutsFileData.append("#" + str(numOfLayouts));
  layoutsFileData.append(layoutName);
  for (int i = 0; i < layoutPositions.size(); i++) {
    layoutsFileData.append(layoutPositions.get(i));
  }
  layoutsFileData.append("");
  numOfLayouts += 1;
  layoutsFileData.set(0, str(numOfLayouts));
  
  saveAndUpdate();
}

void saveAndUpdate() {
  saveStrings("data/layouts.txt", layoutsFileData.toArray());
}

boolean checkFileStructure() {
  
  InputStream input = createInput("layouts.txt");
  
  if (input == null) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
}

public void launchNewLayoutWindow() {
  newLayoutWindow = new ChildApplet(2, displayWidth / 2 - 400, displayHeight / 2 - 225, 800, 450);
}

// New Layouts Window --------------------------------------------------------
class ChildApplet extends PApplet {
  int id, vx, vy, vw, vh;
  int bckColor;
  PFont f_bebasNeueBoldNewLayout;
  
  void easyTextNewLayout(String textDisplay, float textXPos, float textYPos, float textFontSize, color textColor, int textFontAlignX, int textFontAlignY) {
  noStroke();
  fill(textColor);
  textFont(f_bebasNeueBoldNewLayout);
  textSize(textFontSize);
  textAlign(textFontAlignX, textFontAlignY);
  text(textDisplay, textXPos, textYPos);
}
  

  ChildApplet(int id, int vx, int vy, int vw, int vh) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.vx = vx;
    this.vy = vy;
    this.vw = vw;
    this.vh = vh;

    PApplet.runSketch(new String[] {this.getClass().getName()}, this);
  }

  void settings() {
    size(vw, vh, P2D);
    smooth(0);
    println("Creating window "+ id);
  }

  void setup() {
    windowMove(vx, vy);
    windowResizable(true);
    
    cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
    f_bebasNeueBoldNewLayout = createFont(parentPath + "/data/" + "Bebas Neue Pro Bold.otf", 20);
    ControlFont cf_inputFont = new ControlFont(createFont(parentPath + "/data/" + "Bebas Neue Pro Bold.otf",20));
        
    cp5.addTextfield("input")
     .setCaptionLabel("") 
     .setColorCaptionLabel(color(#12284B))
     .setPosition(15,40)
     .setSize(400,40)
     .setFocus(true)
     .setColor(color(#F2F4F3))
     .setFont(cf_inputFont)
     ;
          
  }

  void draw() {
    
    background(#F2F4F3);
    windowTitle("WarBoard - Create New Layout");
    
    easyTextNewLayout("Layout Name:", 15,15,20,color(#12284B),LEFT,TOP);
  }
}
// New Layouts Window --------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried applying some changes to the JFrame? Although I don't understand that too much and any implementation or fix online I've tried using relating to JFrame did not work and most likely was due to me not using it properly. I understand that you can pass parameters through the second applet (window) but those have not worked either to fix this solution.

Comment: See https://discourse.processing.org/t/prevent-one-processing-window-from-closing-others/13719/5

Answer (score 0):

The following source code uses the default Processing primary window for use with cp5 controls and standard graphics in combination with a secondary JFrame which uses a separate thread for Swing components.  Please see if this demo has the behaviour that you are looking for.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import controlP5.*;

javax.swing.JFrame frame;
java.awt.Canvas canvas;

JFrame wnd2;
JLabel label;

PFont font;

final int _wndW = 1600;
final int _wndH = 900;

ControlP5 cp5;
controlP5.Button layoutBtn;

void label(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
  label = new JLabel();
  label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
  label.setBounds(x, y, w, h);
  label.setText("Layout Name:");
  label.setToolTipText("label");
  wnd2.add(label);
  label.repaint();
}

void textField(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
  JTextField txtFld = new JTextField("");
  txtFld.setBounds(x, y, w, h);
  wnd2.add(txtFld);
  txtFld.setToolTipText("text field");
  // **** Action **** //
  txtFld.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
    void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
      // label.setText(txtFld.getText());
    }
  }
  );
  txtFld.repaint(); // To make it visible after export application.
}

void buildLayoutWnd() {
  wnd2 = new JFrame("Window Two");
  wnd2.setBounds(800, 300, 800, 450);
  wnd2.setVisible(false); // Don't show until asked
  wnd2.setLayout(null);
  label(30, 10, 100, 30);
  textField(30, 40, 280, 30);
}

void setup() {
  size(_wndW, _wndH);
  frame = (javax.swing.JFrame) ((processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas) surface.getNative()).getFrame();
  canvas = (processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas) ((processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT)surface).getNative();
  surface.setTitle("WarBoard - V.0.1");
  font = createFont("Menlo-Bold", 18);
  javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      buildLayoutWnd(); // Builds components on EventDispatchThread
    }
  }
  );

  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);

  layoutBtn = cp5.addButton("layout")
    .setPosition(20, 30)
    .setSize(160, 24)
    .setCaptionLabel("New Layout")
    .setFont(font)
    ;
}

void draw() {
  fill(color(255, 0, 0));
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(4.0);
  circle(_wndW/2, _wndH/2, 400);
}

void layout() {
  wnd2.setVisible(true);
}
```